# Is it possible to rename a xls file already in use?

Tags: c++, excel

I am new to this forum. I am writing a program to sync files from one machine to another. While it works fine, I am facing some issues with excel files (.xls, .xlsx). Assume I have backed a xls file from client C1 and updated the same to other client say C2. This happens incrementally by librsync algorithm.

Now the scenario is:

I have a file `a.xls` in both C1 and C2 and this file is getting modified from C1 and needs to be updated to C2. During this time if the file (with the previous version) already opened in C2, I can't update it in the same name. Normally while such update to C2, we used to write in a temporary file (`a.xls.tmp`) and after this has been completed, `a.xls.tmp` will be renamed to a.xls. This rename option failed as `a.xl`s was already opened in C2.

But this is not the only case. Sometimes Anti Virus or other backup products may lock the excel file and again this rename operation gets failed. Because of these factors, I don't exactly know whether the file was in use in target machine (here C2).

I would appreciate if you can give some suggestions how to handle such cases programatically. I am using C++ for my case.

Thanks,
venkat

Comment: Just helping brainstorm...are C1 & C2 on the same network? If so, could you check read-only status before performing your operation?

Comment: or could you initially name it .xlsx, then at the end of your operation, loop through your directory, search for filenames containing a certain string, and rename to .xls once read-write status for said file is confirmed? Not pretty...I know...

Comment: @EricJ, Sorry for the delayed response. In my case C1 and C2 may be either in the same network or different network. In C2 already the target file is opened. So I can't initially name it in the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, it's not possible to rename (or delete) a file that is currently open. There is, as far as I know, no way around that. The only way is to wait until the other process has closed the file. Which of course could be a while if it's something that holds the file open.

Comment: I believe yes the only solution is to wait till other process has closed the file and rename the tmp file back to xls file.